# How do i use a DISTINCT clause with this query in order to eliminate duplicate results?

Tags: php, html, mysql, editplus

```
<?php 

  $k = $_GET['K'];

  $terms = explode(" ", $k);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

  foreach ( $terms as $each) {

          $i++;

      if($i == 1)

      $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";

      else

        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
```

}

require("connect.php");

$query = mysql_query($query);

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows > 0){

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

```
        $id = $rows['id'];
        $title = $rows['title'];
        $description = $rows['descriptions'];
        $keywords = $rows['keywords'];
        $link = $rows['link'];


        echo "<h2><a href = '$link'> $title </a></h2> 
        $description <br /> <br />";
```

}

}else

echo "No results found for \"**$k**\"";

mysql_close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT *FROM search WHERE ";
```

Comment: I'm still getting duplicate results. I've added extra code at the top to help determine why this may be .

Comment: All is good! I managed to fix it. Thanks for you help! much appreciated.